# ASP.NET MVC controller upload photo and save folder path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The method I use works on other servers. It works on my computer but not on the server I just rented.

```
public JsonResult SaveRegesterPhoto(string mImage)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mImage))
     { 
         return Json("عکس نرسید", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
     };            

     var t = mImage.Substring(22);  // remove data:image/png;base64,

     byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t);
     Image image;

     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
     {
         image = Image.FromStream(ms);
     }

     var randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 20) + ".png";
     var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/Admin/"), randomFileName);

     image.Save(fullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

     return Json(mImage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: "~/Photos/Admin/" seems a _very_ specific path. Like the answer says: are you sure your asp.net server has write access to that location?

Comment: instead of `dotnet run` , try use `sudo dotnet run`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the hosting company isn’t blocking functionality, and that your application has permission to write to the new server.

I recall this happening to me with GoDaddy back in the day. Stuff I would prototype, and demo to my client on my dev server, wouldn’t work once deployed to GoDaddy’s environment. Recall taking hours to figure out what the heck was happening, and taking many more hours to find a workaround.

Any error message detail you can provide will help us help you, i.e. browser dev tools error messages and network tab detail, any log messages generated at the server, or messages from logging you have built into your code, etc.

And if I had to hazard a guess without additional information, I might look at directory permissions. Does your application have permission to save the file?